# Why does FOLDERID_ProgramFiles return "C:\Program Files (x86)"?

Tags: c++, windows

```cpp
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string fun(REFKNOWNFOLDERID  val) {
    ITEMIDLIST* pIDList;
    if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderIDList (val, 0, NULL, & pIDList))
    {
        char cpath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
        if (TRUE == SHGetPathFromIDList(pIDList, cpath))
            return cpath;
    }
    return "failed";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "--> " << fun(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--> " << fun(FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--> " << fun(FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
--> C:\Program Files (x86)
--> C:\Program Files (x86)
--> failed
```

I compile it using `cl.exe test.cpp shell32.lib`.

I was expecting "C:\Program Files" for `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles`. My system is x64 based. Why am I getting "Program Files (x86)"?

Comment: Because your executable is x86?

Comment: Have you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-64-bit-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160) for using CL for 64-bit systems?

Comment: On a side note: you are leaking the memory output by `SHGetKnownFolderIDList()`: "*The caller is responsible for freeing the returned PIDL when it is no longer needed by calling [ILFree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-ilfree).*" You should be using [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) instead (though, you still have to free its output memory, too).

Comment: ok after using x64 cl.exe I was able to see the c:\Program Files. For that I had to run "vcvars64.bat" and x64's cl.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are compiling your application as a 32bit executable, even though you are running it on a 64bit system.  So `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles` is mapping to the 32bit `Program Files (x86)` folder.

This is especially evident by the fact that `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` is failing, per the [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) documentation:

> FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64
>
> This value is not supported on 32-bit operating systems. **It also is not supported for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit operating systems.** Attempting to use FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 in either situation results in an error. See Remarks for more information.

This is covered in more detail in the documentation's [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid#remarks) section:

> The interpretation of certain KNOWNFOLDERID values depends on whether the folder is part of a 32-bit or 64-bit application and whether that application is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. If your application needs to distinguish between, for example, Program Files and Program Files (x86), you must use the right KNOWNFOLDERID for the situation.
>
> The following tables summarize the KNOWNFOLDERID use in those cases.
>
> FOLDERID_ProgramFiles
>
> | Operating System | Application | KNOWNFOLDERID | Default Path | CSIDL Equivalent |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
> | 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
> | 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 (not supported under 32-bit operating systems) | Not applicable | Not applicable |
> | 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
> | 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
> | 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | None |
> | 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
> | 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
> | 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 (not supported for 32-bit applications) | Not applicable | Not applicable |

This 32bit/64bit issue also affects `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesCommon` and `FOLDERID_System`, too.